# The adjective "sound" (e.g. in sound formulation; i.e., involving the use of good judgment)

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais

What is the proper way to interpret in French the sound+noun construction:

> Sound strategy, sound formulation, sound advice, and so on.

(that is, involving the use of good judgment, and therefore likely to be effective)

E.g.,

> Sound formulations must be first formulated and tested.

Lacking of specific context, Google translate provides a different interpretation:

> Les formulations sonores doivent d'abord être formulées et testées.

In the specific context discussed above, should one use

> formulations judicieuses, formulations solides, formulations fiables, something other

?

Comment: **Sensé(e)(s)** me semble, dans ce contexte, la meilleure traduction.

Comment: Agreed with @aCOSwt. Also, funny enough, when I read the title of this question I thought the same way Google did :p

Comment: Why do you consider the mistake of Google "strange"? It seems very understandables as a mistake.

Comment: @LaurentS. Ok may be I exaggerate a bit. But I would prefer something like formulations solides in this context (as the examples given by Linguee).

Comment: Well it's one of those cases were there could be many possible translations, and several meanings, so with a limited context I can totally imagine Google can not "guess" too correctly which meaning you're willing to convey...

Comment: I think it can be translated like "good" in your context. The french language has 4* less words in its dictionary. I concluded that with an english dictionary : https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

- *stratégie solide*, *stratégie robuste*
- *bonne formulation*